# How to change python while RunTime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code the run..

```
counter =0
while 1:
    counter +=1
    print('test1')
    if counter == 12345:
        exit(1)
```

How can I change this code while it run so instead of `exit(1)` will be `print('hi')`

Comment: Can you elaborate on "while it's running"? Where do you expect to be changing the code _from_?

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output?

Comment: @mhhabib I have edit my post

Comment: your code will print('test1')

Comment: Do you mean when the counter will `12345` it will print `hi` then the code will exit?

Comment: @mhhabibI want that process will `print ('hi')` ***instead*** exit the code

Comment: Add `print ('hi')` before the exit line

Comment: @mhhabib This code is already running, I want to edit it while runtime , not to exec new process

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible to do inside a single file -- the Python interpreter appears to load the entire file in memory before running it, and reloading the current file is impossible with how Python is built.

However, [you can reload a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module). Knowing this, you can do something like:

```
# main.py
import importlib
import some_module
import time
counter = 0
while 1:
    print("Counter is", counter)
    importlib.reload(some_module)
    some_module.some_function()
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
```

```py
# some_module.py
def some_function():
    print("This is the original function")
```

Now, you can edit `some_module.py`, and the change will be applied to the currently running program:

```
...
Counter is 16
This is the original function
Counter is 17
This is the original function
Counter is 18
This is the original function
Counter is 19
This is the original function
Counter is 20
I just edited the file!
Counter is 21
I just edited the file!
Counter is 22
I just edited the file!
Counter is 23
I just edited the file!
Counter is 24
I just edited the file!
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code , may be help you

```
counter = 0
while 1:
counter += 1
print('test1')
    if counter == 12345:
       continue
print('hi')
```

when loop will stop it will print("hi")

Comment: I want to change running code while runtime , not run a new code